# Tar restore with removal of pathname components

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, tar

I use `tar` about once every 10 years and made a backup off a failed inaccessible drive that luckily worked fine. Except that instead of backing up just `/home` (and everything under it), it backed up `/path/to/home`.

So for example, when I just extract with a simple `tar xzvf mytarfile.tar.gz` in my home directory it creates a sub dir called `path/` and in that a `to/` and finally the `home/` that I really want to appear `../../../` above.

So again, what I'm getting is:

```
/home/myhomedir/path/to/home/allthefilesIwant
```

And what I WANT is:

```
/home/myhomedir/allthefilesIwant
```

Is there any way to get `tar` to strip this extraneous path that's prepended to the home dir content I want to restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `--strip-components=NUMBER` to your `tar` command.

In your example (`/home/myhomedir/path/to/home/allthefilesIwant`), you should set `NUMBER` to 3.